# Call a class method for NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, class-method

I have this code and I want to call this class method to obtain some parameters for an imageView but I don't know how to call it, can you help me ?

```
+ (NSArray*)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)xx andY:(int)yy count:(int)count
```

Comment: I don't understand, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: What do you mean by 'how to call it'? Don't you know the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call that method using your class name.

If your class is like:

```
@interface myClass

+ (NSArray*)getRGBAsFromImage:(UIImage*)image atX:(int)xx andY:(int)yy count:(int)count

@end
```

you can call this method like:

```
NSArray *temp = [myClass getRGBAsFromImage:yourImage atX:x andY:y count:count];
```

Answer (score 0):

To call it you just use the class name...

If this is on UIImage then...

```
[UIImage getRGBAsFromImage:someImage atX:xVal andY:yVal count:countVal];
```